# Android project there is no output dir after gradle build success?

Tags: android, gradle

I am learning Gradle for Android recently. For learning impressively, i create all android application files manually.

my project dirs as below

- **package name : com.wonbin.gradledemo**
- **project build.gradle**

  ```
  buildscript {

          repositories {
                  jcenter()
          }

          dependencies {
                  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
          }
  }
  allprojects {
          repositories {
                  jcenter()
          }
  }
  ```
- **app module build.gradle:**

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {

          compileSdkVersion 23
          buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
          defaultConfig {
                  applicationId "com.wonbin.gradledemo"
                  minSdkVersion 15
                  targetSdkVersion 23
                  versionCode 1
                  versionName "1.0"
                  testInstrumentationRunner "adroid.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
          }
          buildTypes {
                  debug {
                  }
                  release {
                          minifyEnabled false
                          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
                  }
          }
          lintOptions {
              htmlReport true
              htmlOutput file("lint-results.html")
          }
   }

  dependencies {

              compile fileTree(dir:'libs',include:['*.jar'])
                      androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',{
                          exclude group: 'com.android.support',module: 'support-annotations'})
              compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
              testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
      }
  ```

./gradlew build    is successful and there are 'intermediates' and 'generated'
dirs , but no outputs dir, i don't know what to do!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: any information needed please comment

Comment: In app module (MyApp/app/build). There is outputs/apk/app-debug.apk .
i am so sorry. please close it ,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not only to build, but to assemble it as well.
To do this you can run a gradle task

```
assembleDebug
```

Or use  `Build` -> `Build APK` main menu item

Comment: thanks for answering.   problem solved !  there are two  dirs  named "build" generated by gradle.  one is in root directory(MyApp/build); the other is in app module (MyApp/app/build).

Comment: thanks for answering.   problem solved !  there are two  dirs  named "build" generated by gradle.  one is in root directory(MyApp/build); the other is in app module (MyApp/app/build).

 There is outputs/apk/app-debug.apk .

BTW :  build task include assemble and check.  assemble task include assembleDebug and assembleRelease
thanks

Comment: maybe  use "depend on"  instead of "include" better

Comment: @wonbin2011, if the answer is correct, please mark it as a `correct`.

Comment: @Ahmad It is correct. If **you think** that it is not correct - provide some proofs.

Comment: @wonbin2011 You said it in the comment above! "BTW : build task include assemble and check"

Comment: According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185165/which-are-the-differences-between-gradle-assemble-and-gradle-build-taks
buildRelease depends on assembleRelease. So it is in contrary to your answer.