# What are the differences between gradle assemble and gradle build tasks?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

If I am not wrong `gradle assemble` does run `gradle assembleDebug` and `gradle assembleRelease`, but I believe `gradle build` also does the same, so what are the different between them both?

Comment: When I run `buildRelease` I do not get the `.apk` files, only the log files. However, when running `assembleRelease`, I _do_ get the `.apk` files. Odd.

Comment: And `assemble` seems to always take a minimum time, let's say 10s, while `build` runs as fast as 1s if there's no code change.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

`assemble` will build your artifacts, and `build` will assemble your artifacts with additional checks.

`build` depends on `assemble`, so `build` is sort of a superset of `assemble`

You can have a look on the tasks that will be executed by using the `--dry-run` flag. e.g.

```
gradlew build --dry-run
```

You will see that apart from `assemble` also `lint` and `test` will be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe that running with --dry-run is the way to have any further undestanding

Comment: What do you mean by "additional checks"

Comment: @AjayS `lint` and `test`

Comment: From my last experience, this answer is wrong. When I run assembleRelease, I get the output apk. When I run buildRelease, no apk is generated. Also, I run both tasks with --dry-run, as suggested above and it seems that build is not running assemble underneath.

Comment: I wonder if the Android plugin implements build/assemble differently than the Java plugin. I just posted an answer to this question that shows two conflicting diagrams. But one is discussing Android and the other Java.

Comment: so 'assemble' does a build, and 'build' does an assemble??  That makes no sense

Comment: @johnktejik gradle has a lot of different tasks that depend on more tasks... build depends on assemble, so running a build will also run assemble among other things...assemble will depend on assembleDebug as well as assembleRelease... etc. If you always run a full build your build time will be quite slow, so you can only choose to build what you need, e.g. `assembleMyFlavorDebug` to avoid building everything every time... That's how a lot of (all?) build systems work

Comment: @DavidMedenjak So how come `build` is *always* faster for me? Even if I'm not running a `clean`, running `assemble` is always 10s at least, while `build` get as fast as 1s after a few builds without any code change.

Comment: @DielsonSales profiling builds is hard as there are a lot of things that play together. But you should be able to [run build scans](https://scans.gradle.com/) and compare your results in detail

Answer (score 38):

From `gradle tasks --all`:

```
Build tasks
-----------
assemble - Assembles the outputs of this project.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
```

`build` is effectively `assemble` + `check` (and `check` is `test` + any linting tasks).

Comment: I've just tested it here on Gradle 6.8.2 and `build` didn't run any `check`. In fact, it was almost the same time as `assemble`. `build` executed 105 tasks while `assemble` executed 108 tasks.

Comment: @DielsonSales Try using https://github.com/dorongold/gradle-task-tree to see what the task graph for `build` looks like. Perhaps your build configuration is somehow changing things, but normally `build` is literally `assemble` + `check`.

Comment: Looks like gradle-task-tree doesn't work with Gradle 6.8 or later. You can try with gradle 6.7.1, assuming your build is compatible with that version.

Answer (score 28):

There is conflicting information about whether `build` is supposed to depend on `assemble`.

On one hand, [Understanding Gradle: the Build Lifecycle](https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-gradle-the-build-lifecycle-5118c1da613f) shows a graph of task dependencies from where `build` and `assemble` are independent:
[image: Directed acyclic graph for the Java plug-in tasks from the book Gradle Recipes for Android.]

In contrast, the [Gradle user guide for Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) shows that `build` depends on `assemble`, at least for Java projects:

[image: Java plugin - tasks]

This contradicts the graph from "Understanding Gradle." So perhaps the Android plugin implements build/assemble tasks differently from the Java plugin? Or, this behavior changed in some version of Gradle.

Comment: build depends on both check and assemble as seen in the code: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/f351797d5e9ff4184d4cf23312e6f851b1eecb93/subprojects/platform-base/src/main/java/org/gradle/language/base/plugins/LifecycleBasePlugin.java#L82-L89

Answer (score 23):

It's true that according to `gradle tasks` it looks like the `build` is a superset of `assemble`, including tests.
But(!) from my short experience it really looks like it's not the case.

So I ran those 2 commands in the command line using the gradle wrapper with --scan flag after running clean every time.
This is the comparison:

1. Desired built files:

   - After running `assembleDebug` I got all the built files i wanted - `*.apk` and `*.aar` files.
   - After running `buildDebug` I didn't have any of those files.
2. Amount of tasks ran according to the scans:

   - `assembleDebug` - 109 tasks
   - `buildDebug` - 91 tasks
3. Amount of dependencies according to the scan:

   - `assembleDebug` - 172 from 20 configurations
   - `buildDebug` - 104 from 18 configurations
   - It seems like the reason they differ is that in `assembleDebug` in 2 of my 3 sub projects (which are java libraries, not app) there is one more configuration, called `lintClassPath`. This configuration is missing in `buildDebug`.
4. Another point to mention is that when I searched in the tasks list, it seemed like `buildDebug` didn't call `assembleDebug` task and `assembleDebug` didn't call `buildDebug` tasks.
5. And the last interesting thing to mention in this context is that when I ran build from the Android Studio (`Build -> Make Project`), I see in my scan that the command that actually ran was the `assembleDebug`. More specifically, it ran `:app:assembleDebug`.

As you can see, I don't really understand the differences myself, but this is what I found out. If someone can explain it to me and the other users reading here, it could be awesome :)
Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK the build process has a cache mechanism. This is why you see fewer tasks with the build command. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html

Answer (score 2):

> Assemble will build your artifacts, and build will assemble your artifacts with additional checks.

What additional checks? I run the tasks so you don't have to:

```
:app:lint SKIPPED       
:app:bundleDebugClasses SKIPPED     
:app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugUnitTestKotlin SKIPPED       
:app:kaptDebugUnitTestKotlin SKIPPED        
:app:compileDebugUnitTestKotlin SKIPPED     
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild SKIPPED      
:app:javaPreCompileDebugUnitTest SKIPPED        
:app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac SKIPPED      
:app:processDebugUnitTestJavaRes SKIPPED        
:app:testDebugUnitTest SKIPPED      
:app:bundleReleaseClasses SKIPPED       
:app:kaptGenerateStubsReleaseUnitTestKotlin SKIPPED     
:app:kaptReleaseUnitTestKotlin SKIPPED      
:app:compileReleaseUnitTestKotlin SKIPPED       
:app:preReleaseUnitTestBuild SKIPPED        
:app:javaPreCompileReleaseUnitTest SKIPPED      
:app:compileReleaseUnitTestJavaWithJavac SKIPPED        
:app:processReleaseUnitTestJavaRes SKIPPED      
:app:testReleaseUnitTest SKIPPED        
:app:test SKIPPED       
:app:check SKIPPED      
:app:build SKIPPED
```

As you can see, `build` does execute more tasks than `assemble`. Like `lint`, `test`, and `check` tasks.

You can refer the [full tasks here](https://www.diffchecker.com/lCjyhv5k)
The original text is `build` task while the changed text is `assemble` task.

Project used: [Android Sunflower GitHub](https://github.com/android/sunflower/commit/0c4c88fdad2a74791199dffd1a6559559b1dbd4a)

Comment: This is not true for recent versions of the Gradle Wrapper

Answer (score 1):

There is a great plugin which visualize dependencies between tasks:

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.barfuin.gradle.taskinfo

After adding it to your project run e.g. `./gradlew tiTree build`

More in this article: https://tomgregory.com/all-about-the-gradle-task-graph/

Comment: This one is good. Using Gradle 8.1.1, I see clearly that `build` depends on `assemble` and `check`.