# react-native build only (android)

Tags: react-native

**Scenario**

I used `react-native run-android` to build my android project but it also runs the project. Because I'm using an npm plugin to modify my build information I'm only interested in building rather than launching.

**Question**

With react native is it possible to build android files without launching? Theoretically something like `react-native build-android` or `react-native run-android --build-only`

**Extra Info**

I looked into the `help` for `react-native run-android` but didn't see anything promising.

```
$ react-native run-android --help
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/Jackson/Sites/fnmultiapptest/node_modules (11ms)

  react-native run-android [options]
  builds your app and starts it on a connected Android emulator or device

  Options:

    --install-debug           
    --root [string]           Override the root directory for the android build (which contains the android directory) (default: "")
    --flavor [string]         --flavor has been deprecated. Use --variant instead
    --variant [string]        
    --appFolder [string]      Specify a different application folder name for the android source. (default: "app")
    --appId [string]          Specify an applicationId to launch after build. (default: "")
    --appIdSuffix [string]    Specify an applicationIdSuffix to launch after build. (default: "")
    --main-activity [string]  Name of the activity to start (default: "MainActivity")
    --deviceId [string]       builds your app and starts it on a specific device/simulator with the given device id (listed by running "adb devices" on the command line).
    --no-packager             Do not launch packager while building
    --port [number]            (default: 8081)
    --config [string]         Path to the CLI configuration file
    -h, --help                output usage information
```

Comment: I thought that react-native run-android builds and installs... When I want to run I double click the installed app...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to the android directory and run `./gradlew assembleDebug`. You can then manually install.

Comment: under the hood, runAndroid is using `build` more than `assembleDebug` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185165/which-are-the-differences-between-gradle-assemble-and-gradle-build-taks/44185464). But in this case it may not matter.

Comment: `./gradlew assembleRelease` for release

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just with:

```
cd android && ./gradlew build -x lint
```

(use `gradlew.bat` if you run it on windows)

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js#L180