# What's the difference between "gradle clean" and "gradle clean ass" commands?

Tags: java, gradle

Sometimes when I run gradle clean  and then "clean build", I don't get the proper compilation errors, based on my last changes on the java files. But when I run "gradle clean ass" before "gradle build", then java is reporting the correct compilation errors, according to my last changes. So, I was wondering what's the difference between doing "gradle clean" and "gradle clean ass", as only the latter seems to properly clean my project before the build.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44185464/2970947

Comment: `gradle clean ass` is short for `gradle clean assembly`

Comment: actually, it's `assemble`, not `assembly`. build simply depends on assemble, which itself depends on compile. Both tasks compile the exact same way. If one of them doesn't produce the expected errors, it most probably means you just forgot to save your changes. And `clean` is not necessary: gradle knows when to recompile and when not to.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If that is not a duplicate proposal, then what do you mean with that link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which are the differences between gradle assemble and gradle build taks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185165/which-are-the-differences-between-gradle-assemble-and-gradle-build-taks)